# How do you make a live preview site for selling Joomla templates

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I am building a website to sell Joomla templates on but can't find a viable solution for users to see a live preview... any suggestions?

I have tried the template changer extension and it works but is a bit clunky. I was hoping for something like a direct link/url that sets the default template. I know how to make a link to call the template `?template=template_name` but when you navigate a link it returns to the default template.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if the Demo site to preview the Joomla templates was **not** actually a Joomla powered site.

To be honest, it's more simple than you may think.

You will need to create a static HTML site with a dropdown list of some sort, showing all your Joomla template names. In this HTML page, you will also need an iframe.

When one of the options is selected, you will need to change the `src` attribute of the iframe to load the selected template.

Each template should be on a separate Joomla installation.

Maybe have a look at how [Yootheme have done their Demo page](http://yootheme.com/demo)

Hope this helps